# How to use a custom developed section to be different on each template i includ?

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

I have made a custom Shopify section that I want to include in some custom product templates. But when I include it in template 1 e.g (product-temp1) it works for 1 time and when I add it to template 2 it shows the data of template 1 which I don't want.

Anyone who can help me out to make it unique for each template?

Comment: You need to duplicate the section also same as template files, if you add the same section then it shows the data from the past and override it. so simply use like this section-1, template-1 and section-2, template-2 and so on

Comment: Is there any other way so I can make multiple templates and 1 section only. to use as a separate for each of the template

Comment: Nopes, in theme files you can't use it, you need to use any 3rd party page builder that has the option to build their own custom elements like Shogun page builder

Comment: What kind of custom data do you need for each page? It might be that you could solve your issue by creating metafields on the appropriate products.  Metafields are a native feature of Shopify but there's no* native way to edit them.  There are plenty of apps that can edit metafields at varying price points that might help, too.

Comment: * Note: You _can_ edit metafields directly through the bulk product editor if you specify a special page in your URL bar. This article is one that I found that shows you how to do it: https://www.sunbowlsystems.com/blogs/how-to/metafields-in-shopify-without-using-an-app

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have a section with blocks inside and I want to have different on each template.

Answer (score 0):

In Shopify, you can't use the custom section twice. You will need to recreate the custom section again.

For example:
you have a custom section: welcome-section.liquid and you are using it in product-temp1 template and now you want this custom section in product-temp2 then you will need to recreate a new section like welcome-again-section.liquid. Copy the code of welcome-section.liquid and paste it in welcome-again-section.liquid section. Then use this welcome-again-section.liquid section in your product-temp2 template.